# unable use columns defined in xmltable

Tags: sql, oracle

Getting error while running the below query

```
  select xt.IssueDate, xt.SequenceNumber  from xml_tab x ,
          XMLTABLE('/EmployeeInfo'
                   PASSING x.xml_data COLUMNS
                   "IssueDate" varchar2(10) path '@IssueDate',
                   "SequenceNumber" integer path '@SequenceNumber'
            ) xt;
```

error I am getting

> ORA-00904: "XT"."SEQUENCENUMBER": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 114 Column: 22

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing [quoted and non-quoted identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129). The `columns` clause in the XMLTable call is defining SQL-type names, not XML-type names.

You can either quote both:

```
select xt."IssueDate", xt."SequenceNumber"  from xml_tab x ,
          XMLTABLE('/EmployeeInfo'
                   PASSING x.xml_data COLUMNS
                   "IssueDate" varchar2(10) path '@IssueDate',
                   "SequenceNumber" integer path '@SequenceNumber'
            ) xt;
```

or preferably quote neither:

```
select xt.IssueDate, xt.SequenceNumber  from xml_tab x ,
          XMLTABLE('/EmployeeInfo'
                   PASSING x.xml_data COLUMNS
                   IssueDate varchar2(10) path '@IssueDate',
                   SequenceNumber integer path '@SequenceNumber'
            ) xt;
```